# Log in with different browsers MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, formsauthentication

On my MVC 4 application I have a log in page which saves a user Id and transfers user to a Dashboard page in this way:

```
 var user = _userService.GetUserByCredentials(accountCredentials.Username.Trim(), accountCredentials.Password);

if (user != null)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Id.ToString(), true);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
}
```

If I log in with, for ex. Chrome I get transfered nicely to `http://localhost:63377/Dashboard` on which I use `User.GetUserId()`(on Dashboard controller):

```
_user = _userService.GetUserById(User.GetUserId());
Session["NimbleUser"] = _user.Firstname + " " + _user.Lastname;
```

An error is thrown if I copy the url(`http://localhost:63377/Dashboard`) to a Firefox, IE,... my `_user` on Dashboard controller is then `null`, probably because `User.GetUserId()` is `null`. How do I repair this so I can copy url to other browsers and that my application still works?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the `User.GetUserId()` returns null then obviously the `GetUserById` will fail. If UserId is null, redirect the user to the Login page.

Comment: You're right. That is how I will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auth cookie is stored by the browser, for the browser. You'll have to perform the login with each of your browsers that you want to use.